# C# Operator '+' cannot be applied to operand of type 'bool'

Tags: c#

I have searched for the answer to this question. I found similar sorts of questions, but those do not resolve the issue I have.

The last line of code is where I get the error: Operator '+' cannot be applied to operand of type 'bool' Here is the code:

```
public partial class frmLogin : Form
{
    public frmLogin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        employee oEmployee = new employee();
        oEmployee.LoginEvent += new LoginEventHandler(oEmployee_LoginEvent);
        oEmployee.Login(txtName.Text, txtPassword.Text);
    }

    void oEmployee_LoginEvent(string loginName, bool status)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login Status: ", + status);  Here is where the issue is
    }
```

Comment: Delete the comma

Comment: just do status.ToString()  that should fix the issue

Comment: Thanks. Deleting the comma worked as did status.ToString().

Answer (score 1):

Because of the comma, you are printing two values, the second of which ( + status ) is a unary prefixed + operator applied to a bool value. There is no such operator, so the error.

You can get rid of the comma ("Login Status: " + status.ToString())  in which case the + is a concatenation operator, or you can get rid the plus "Login Status: ", status.ToString()) and print two strings.

Comment: C R, thanks for the response. The explanation is very helpful. If I understand correctly, my adding the comma to the line told the compiler there are two arguments. However, the variable status being a bool needs a single argument hence as you said, the error.